# jQuery - How can I get element with id when the id includes '$' symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about jQuery. I have an element whose id is CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$. So I tested jQuery in chrome developer tools as following

```
$('#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$')
```

However, the tool said

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$' is not a valid selector.
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is there anyway to select the element with that id?

Comment: BTW, that isn't actually jQuery; the console has its own `$`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape `$` using `\\`.

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($('#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT\\$108\\$').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$">Hello</div>
```

The other, **non-recommended** way is to use attribute selectors using `[id="TheID"]`:

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($('[id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$"]').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$">Hello</div>
```

**Note:** To be precise, the error shows that you are using the [**Command Line API**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference) and not jQuery. Can you check if jQuery has been really loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard DOM methods then convert it to a jQuery object, as shown below:

```js
var el =document.getElementById("CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$");
var $el = $(el);

console.log($el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$108$"><span>
```